# APDU via USB Connection

Tags: java, android, usb, apdu, smartcard-reader

I want to create an android app to find my micro-usb (smartcard reader device), so I have a problem with receive data in smartcard (I sent an APDU that is 0x... to smartcard by method usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer. But I don’t know how to receive data or something that answer back (It have to answer a data in card back to me after I sent command). And when it answer back how can I encode or translate hex to string?

I guess, (ref from code) I have a 2 endpoint so I have question about endpointIn and endpointOut. What are these params? How can I use it to send and receive data between device and app? I think right, or not? And what is BroadcastReceiver do?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);   
   //register the broadcast receiver
   mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
  registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

  registerReceiver(mUsbDeviceReceiver, new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED));
  registerReceiver(mUsbDeviceReceiver, new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED));

  connectUsb();
}
```

Here is connectUSB method.

```
private void connectUsb() {
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
   "connectUsb()",
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


  searchEndPoint();

   if (usbInterfaceFound != null) {
  setupUsbComm();

   threadUsbTx = new ThreadUsbTx(usbDeviceConnection, endpointOut);
   threadUsbTx.start();

   //bytes are APDU to send for get data from card.
   threadUsbTx.insertCmd(
   new byte[]{(byte) 0xA0, (byte) 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x3F, 0x00});
   threadUsbTx.insertCmd(
   new byte[]{(byte)0x80, (byte)0xb0, 0x00, 0x04, 0x02, 0x00, 0x0d});
   threadUsbTx.insertCmd(
   new byte[]{0x00, (byte)0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0d});
   }
  }
```

Here is class ThreadUsbTx..

```
class ThreadUsbTx extends Thread {
   boolean running;

  UsbDeviceConnection txConnection;
  UsbEndpoint txEndpoint;
  Queue<byte[]> cmdQueue;
   byte[] cmdToSent;


  ThreadUsbTx(UsbDeviceConnection conn, UsbEndpoint endpoint) {
   txConnection = conn;
   txEndpoint = endpoint;
   cmdQueue = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
   cmdToSent = null;

   running = true;
  }

   public void setRunning(boolean r) {
   running = r;
  }

   public void insertCmd(byte[] cmd) {
   synchronized (cmdQueue) {
   cmdQueue.add(cmd);
  }
  }

   @Override
   public void run() {

   while (running) {

   synchronized (cmdQueue) {
   if (cmdQueue.size() > 0) {
   cmdToSent = cmdQueue.remove();
  }
  }

   if (cmdToSent != null) {

   final int usbResult = usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(
   txEndpoint,
   cmdToSent,
   cmdToSent.length,
   0);

   final String s = new String(cmdToSent);
  String result = null;

   try {
  result = new String(cmdToSent,"TIS620"); // To Thai language
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }

   final String finalResult = result;
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
   finalResult+" "+String.format("%040x",cmdToSent),
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
  });
   cmdToSent = null;
   }
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Does your reader expect APDUs to be directly transfered over the USB connection or does it require some intermediate protocol (e.g. does it follow the CCID device class like typical smartcard reader do)?

Comment: I know just only APDU can commu with smartcard, so I have an example app that it can send APDU through USB connection. And I decompiled it, found they use USB connection, too. If I have to know anything please advice me more. Thank you.

Comment: Your English is OK, just watch out not to put spaces before `.` and `?` and consistently write "I" (it is never "i")

Comment: vendorID = 1423
ProductID=38208
proname = EMV Smartcard Reader

thank u again. :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to communicate with the USB Card reader is to use the CCID-Compliant one along with an OTG-Capable phone. Take a look at the App "CCID Reader Application Demo" in Playstore. Also useful [the library](http://android.acs.com.hk) available [here](http://downloads.acs.com.hk/drivers/en/ACS-LIB-Android-112-A.zip). Otherwise you have to implement more or less the CCID-behaviour in your code